# zeroc-ice34 has been comiled and installed but it can not be detected when install a debian package

Tags: ice

I'm using Ubuntu16.04 and trying install a package named "nrt" through "apt-get install". 
The output after running "sudo  apt-get install nr" is as follows:

> ```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  nrt : Depends: libboost1.48-all-dev but it is not installable
>        Depends: zeroc-ice34 but it is not installable
>        Depends: libzeroc-ice34-dev but it is not installable
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

1. I have managed to compile and install ice3.4.0. And I have added the corresponding paths to "PATH". However, it still complained that zeroc-ice34 is not installable.
2. The default boost version on my computer is 1.54 but "nrt" needs boost-1.48.

How can I deal with this problem? Is there some way to switch default boost version?

Comment: Hi Zong, the package manager apt, is complaining that it cannot install the dependencies for nrt, looking at ubuntu repositories there is only ice 3.5 packages, how did you get "nrt" package?

Comment: Seen from http://nrtkit.org/, "nrt" is a professional and private robotics programming tool. The nrt binary package was released several years ago and is not maintained any longer. Now only the source code of nrt is maintained on a subversion (SVN) server. However, a authorized user name and password is needed for access (http://nrtkit.org/documentation/g_GetNRT.html).

Comment: I sent an email to the author but no reply is received. So I tried to install nrt binary package by adding its ppa address. After days of effort, I have solved some dependency issues, but zeroc-ice34 hampered me. Thanks for your answer,  José.

Comment: You might be able to build `zeroc-ice34` from the source packages, but this can be more work than expected, you will have to download the ubuntu sources for the package build it in your machine and install the resulting package files

Comment: As stated in my question, I have succeeded to build  and installed ice34 from the source code. However, it can not be found. And I'm wondering whether ice34 is equivalent to zeroc-ice34.

Comment: I mean you will have to build your own ubuntu zeroc-ice34 packages, that is not the same as build and install Ice from sources. One you are able to build zeroc-ice34 packages and install them. But even if you do that there isn't any guarantee that the nrt package that was build with a different GCC vesrion will work with the new zeroc-ice34 package

Comment: OK. I gave up. Thanks,  José.